# Roots of polynomials $\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x)=x^l+x^{l-1}+x^{l-2}+\cdots+x^2+x+1$,

$p$ being prime, $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod {p^2}$  if $p\equiv 1\pmod l$ or $p=l$ has $l$ roots, otherwise it has none.

So what can be said about $f(x)\equiv0\pmod {p^2}$ (The form of the prime $p$ and number of roots)

Thank you.

Comment: It might help to look at $(x-1)f(x)=x^{l+1}-1$ which will have the same roots except for the case $x\equiv 1\bmod p$

Comment: Thats what I considered first but did not help me with $mod \ p^2$

Comment: Building a little bit on Mark's suggestion. Are you familiar with the result that  (apart from the nilpotent residue classes of multiples of $p$) the (multiplicative) group of residue classes modulo $p^2$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$? For $p$ odd, that is.

Comment: Honestly no...Can you elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the product
$$
g(x)=f(x)(x-1)=x^{\ell+1}-1.
$$
Any zero of $g(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}$ must be coprime to $p$, and therefore an element of $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}^*$.

This group is [known to be cyclic of order $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) (my knee-jerk reaction was to treat the case $p=2$ separately, but that is unnecessary, when studying residue classes modulo a **square** of a prime).

It is well known that the equation $x^m=1$ has $\gcd(m,n)$ solutions in a cyclic group of order $n$. Therefore we can conclude that
$g(x)$ has $\gcd(\ell+1,p(p-1))$ zeros in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}$. To get the number of zeros of $f(x)$ you need to subtract one unless $x=1$ is also a zero of $f(x)$, i.e. unless $p^2\mid \ell+1$.

Comment: So  $f(x)$ has $\ell$ solutions $mod\ p^2 $. What about the form of $p$?

Comment: ? I only said that it has $\ell$ solutions, if $\ell+1\mid p(p-1)$.